# Epiphany web app not working

Tags: webapps, epiphany

I have Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell installed. I installed epiphany web browser using this method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

Now I can apparently create web apps from the "File" menu, but I can neither directly start them straight after creation (nothing happens clicking on launch) nor can I find them within "applications" but I can see them using "about:application".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).